# Tablesorter Not Sorting AJAX Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I am building a table from a CSV file using AJAX. The table looks fine. But no matter what I try, I can't get tablesorter to make it sortable.
I've tried just about every solution I could find here on stackoverflow. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tablesorter.com/docs/css/jq.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "MovieList.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });

});

function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(",");
    var lines = [];
var thelist
var columns = [];
//thelist = "<thead><tr>"
//for (i in headers) {
//headers[i] = headers[i].replace(/"/g,"")
//thelist += "<th>"+headers[i]+"</th>"
//}
//thelist += "</tr></thead><tbody>"
for (i in allTextLines) {
thelist +="<tr>"
columns = allTextLines[i].split(",")
if (i > 0) {
for (i in columns) {
columns[i] = columns[i].replace(/"/g,"")
thelist += "<td>"
thelist += columns[i]
thelist += "</td>"
} }
thelist += "</tr>"
} 
//thelist += "</tbody>"


$("#test").append(thelist);

};   

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of problems with your code but you were heading in the right direction.

1: You're missing a lot of semicolons. There are too many to point out but check the plunker.

2: You need to include jQuery before you include Tablesorter because Tablesorter relies on jQuery.

3: To use Tablesorter on a table, that table must have a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. I can see you've commented out the code which adds it to your table but you do need it. The [docs](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Getting-Started) don't highlight it very well but it's under "Getting Started".

4: AJAX calls are asynchronous which means your code won't necessarily run in order. You should initialize Tablesorter within the AJAX call after you've processed the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "MovieList.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        processData(data);
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    }
});
```

5: When you are adding rows to the tbody, you are adding an extra row at the start when `i === 0`. Move this code `thelist += "<tr>";` inside your loop and if statement.

```
for (var i in allTextLines) {
    var columns = allTextLines[i].split(",");
    if (i > 0) {
        thelist += "<tr>";
        for (var j in columns) {
            thelist += "<td>";
            thelist += columns[j];
            thelist += "</td>";
        }
    }
    thelist += "</tr>";
}
```

6: You are appending the rows to a table called "#test" but initializing Tablesorter on "#myTable".

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/T2K6vq9OXLYGNdAeNIpE?p=preview)

Comment: Semi-colons aren't necessary in many cases in JS, just so you know.

Comment: @Terry you're right but in terms of code readability, they're important for clearly indicating to the reader where the author intended to end the statement. If the author includes them on some statements, but not on similar statements, it causes the reader (or me at least) to wonder if they meant to end the statement there.

Comment: Nice answer! I also wanted to mention, that if you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can use the [ignore articles parser](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-ignore-articles.html) to ignore "The", "A" and "An" in the titles while sorting.

Comment: There's a lot of information I neglected to give. Amateur here. I initially had the <thead> and <tbody> tags in the jquery. Then I added them to the html, so only the rows would be getting appended. So "test" is the tbody ID, and myTable is the table ID. 
That aside, I will try out your suggestions and hopefully that works! Thanks, brother.

Comment: @jaydo I implemented all of your suggestions and I still can't get it to sort.

Comment: I take it back. Jaydo, your suggestions were 100% the solution. I just missed a '#'. lol